# Google Play Promo Codes

Tags: android, google-play

I want to distribute my app via Google Play but to be visible only to users have my Promo Codes. It's possible in App Store but looks like not possible in Google Play.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Note : I don't want to use Google Play Alpha/Beta tests since I need to provide email address for users. I just want to distribute my app via promo codes (or sth similar) before launching.

Thanks

Comment: does private channel works for you? https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: No it does not help, I want anybody to download my app. Not only people in the domain.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use email addresses for Alpha/Beta testing - just invite users with your Promo Codes to a Google Group or private Google+ community.

If you don't upload a version to the Production channel, it will only be visible to those in the group/community that have access to the Alpha/Beta.

Comment: This is what I want but what Google says about promo codes :
In-app purchases: If you want to offer promo codes for in-app purchases, you need to integrate In-app Promotions in your app. Keep in mind promo codes can't be used for subscriptions or inactive in-app products.

Paid apps: To offer promo codes for paid apps, you can skip this step and begin with step 2.

Comment: What do you mean with "just invite users with your Promo Codes to a Google Group or private Google+ community" ?

Comment: Promo codes don't give access to apps. Creating and inviting people to a Google Group or Google+ community that you've set up for closed beta testing gives them access to the app. And once they're in the community, you can give them promo codes.

Of course, you could also use an [open beta](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213), limit the number of users (although the minimum is 1,000), and make it so that beta users don't have to IAP at all (if you were going to give them promo codes anyways...).

Comment: And once they're in the community, they will be able to download the App. So promo code becomes meaningless for my case. I want to use promo codes for users to install the App. It looks like there is no way. Thanks.